# RStudio/Posit workbench how does it create the URL path

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

I am running a shiny app locally on RStudio/Posit workbench in the browser.

The app just prints its current URL

```
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  verbatimTextOutput("url")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$url <- renderText({
    cd <- session$clientData
    url <-  paste0(cd$url_protocol, "//", cd$url_hostname, cd$url_pathname)
    cat(sprintf("Running on\n  %s\n", url))
    url
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(port = 4218))
```

For example when I run it it reads: `https://POSIT_URL/s/46da136e42a33f0a920f9/p/64dab64d/`.
I am interested in the last bit `64dab64d` and was wondering how this is created. It depends on the port number and seems to be consistent to my session.
Is it possible to generate/predict this number before the app is run?

I suspect it is a hashed value but I couldnt find the right inputs/hash function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, no need to start and stop the app.

From R you can call:

```
rstudioapi::translateLocalUrl(
    url = "http://localhost:8765",
    absolute = TRUE
    )
```

This will return the full externally accessible URL that maps to your localhost address, including the hashed port part.

In [newer builds of posit workbench](https://docs.posit.co/ide/news/#rstudio-2022.12.0353) there is also a command line tool available that you can call from vscode or jupyterlab:
 `/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver-url -l <port number>`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely an answer but a brute-force workaround: start the app, print the URL and stop the app again.
In a function it looks like this

```
# retrieves the URL for a shiny app
get_full_shiny_url <- function(port) {
  server <- function(input, output, session){
    shiny::observe(cat(paste0(
      session$clientData$url_protocol, "//", session$clientData$url_hostname,
      session$clientData$url_pathname, "\n"
    )))
    shiny::stopApp()
  }
  
  capture.output(shiny::shinyApp(shiny::basicPage(), server,
                                 options = list(port = port)))
}
get_full_shiny_url(4812)
#> https://POSIT_URL/s/46da136e42a33f0a920f9/p/64dab64d/
```